# I'm trying to use this codepen CSS effect but the zooming effect does not quite work.

Tags: css, wordpress, templates, hover

I am trying to replicate the zoom #1 hover effect from [this](http://codepen.io/nxworld/pen/ZYNOBZ) codepen.

In this codepen demo, the image zoom-in but the container stays the same size.

Here the css for the image

```
    .hover01 figure img {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
    transform: scale(1);
    -webkit-transition: .3s ease-in-out;
    transition: .3s ease-in-out;
}

.hover01 figure:hover img {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.3);
    transform: scale(1.3);
}
```

The image container also has this code

```
    figure {
    width: 300px;
    height: 200px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background: #fff;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

When I'm using it on my page, my image get scaled.

You can see it on [this](http://www.levelupcoachingclub.com/index.php/coaching-3-2/) page (password : test )

I'm thinking it probably has to do with the overflow:hidden from the container image, but I'm using a template and using firefox inspectors, it seem like the image div container would be #le_body_row_2_col_1_el_1.element-container.cf.condition_small

I have added an overflow:hidden to this div but still no luck.

So I'm clueless right now. I don't have much experience with css/html template customization. Either it's not the overflow properties that i'm missing or i'm not using it on the right div.

If anyone could help that'd be greatly appreciated. Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

i have made demo i hope it will help
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/MKyRrM

```
    .hover01 figure img {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
    transform: scale(1);
    -webkit-transition: .3s ease-in-out;
    transition: .3s ease-in-out;
}
.hover01 figure:hover img {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.3);
    transform: scale(1.3);
}
figure {
    width: 500px;
    height: 450px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background: #fff;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```